# Using Graphite/Grafana for non time based data

Tags: metrics, graphite, grafana

I have been reading through documentation and have been able to get Graphite to receive data I have been sending it. I can definitely see the benefit in tracking things like concurrent users and network load.

But now I have been tasked with implementing it on the client to show things like RAM, and CPU usage. In addition to this, I must also track actions (users buying things). Maybe I am missing a large chunk of the picture here, but I am not sure how I would do these things. Do I need a timestamp? I've also seen plugins for pie charts and such and this would indicate I could perhaps create graphs from devices with different statistics.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're missing anything.

Any data you send on to, say, InfluxDB (as that's what I've used the most) will be timestamped automatically when it arrives - unless you specify an explicit one yourself.

If you're showing, for example, CPU load you can write your query to pick up the latest value, or perhaps an average (mean value) over time, or the max or min over a period of time as appropriate.

Pie charts can also be used successfully to graph relationships over time.

The key is to create a specific query (I use SQL directly) to craft the data used for the panel type. There are excellent examples in the [documentation](http://docs.grafana.org).